# Network port open, but no process attached?

Tags: linux

When I check my server, I found some strange ports:

```
[root@server ~]# netstat -tulnp |grep "-"
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address    Foreign Address    State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049     0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33181    0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049     0.0.0.0:*                      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33252    0.0.0.0:*                      -
```

No program can be found in the output of `netstat -tulnp(with root privilege）`.

How could I find the usage of these ports? How could I judge it's safe or not?

OS: CentOS 5.6 x86_64

Kernel: 2.6.18-238.el5 #1 SMP Thu Jan 13 15:51:15 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

update:

```
# rpcinfo -p
program vers proto   port
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100011    1   udp    824  rquotad
100011    2   udp    824  rquotad
100011    1   tcp    827  rquotad
100011    2   tcp    827  rquotad
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100021    1   udp  33252  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp  33252  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp  33252  nlockmgr
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100021    1   tcp  33181  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp  33181  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp  33181  nlockmgr
100005    1   udp    839  mountd
100005    1   tcp    842  mountd
100005    2   udp    839  mountd
100005    2   tcp    842  mountd
100005    3   udp    839  mountd
100005    3   tcp    842  mountd
```

Comment: no output with `lsof`

Comment: Try `lsof -n -i | grep -i 2049`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are likely to be [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) ports reserved by the [portmapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmap). 2049 is a well known port used by NFS. Your other ports are probably other RPC services. To query the portmapper for a full list of services and their ports use `rpcinfo -p`.

Comment: Thank you, @Andy Brown. As I showed `rpcinfo -p` above, it's no need to worry about that, right?

Comment: If you don't need NFS then it should [be disabled](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-redhat-rhel-fedora-remove-nfs-services/). If you do need it then make sure you've secured it or use a secure alternative, e.g. sshfs.